# Replace all <> if they occur between quotation marks

Tags: regex

How can I update my regular expression to handle all occurrences of `>` (that occur between quotation marks)?

```
\=(("|').*)>(.*("|'))\im
```

Here is a working example: https://regexr.com/4rjnf

If I run my regex on the following string I only replace one occurrence not all.

Source string:  `<div attr='.foo > .bar > .baz'><div>`
Result from my regex: `<div attr='.foo > .bar &gt; .baz'><div>`
My desired result: `<div attr='.foo &gt; .bar &gt; .baz'><div>`

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML/XML. Use a parser instead.

Comment: @anubhava I am editing/sanitising the html prior to saving to a database

Comment: I believe `>` should **already** be `&gt;` in a standard HTML text.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a PHP parser? I am editing/sanitising the html prior to saving to a database